# $.test = function() vs. var test = function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen in jquery the $.function but cant find any explanation.

```
$.test= function() {};
```

what makes the different to:

```
var test= function() {};
```

Comment: The fact that in the first instance you store the function on a property of the jQuery object, while in the second in a local variable. Since none of the above "does" anything by itself, the difference depends entirely on other code.

Comment: the first one adds `test` as a property of the object referred by `$`(jQuery in this case) - the second one creates a variable named `test` which refers to the function.. the problem with this is if it is defined in the global scope then you are polluting global namespace which may collide with other declarations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first assigns a value to the `test` property of the object referenced by the `$` variable (which is found by looking up the scope tree until there is a match for `$` and, given the tags on your question, it is probably the global jQuery object).

The second defines a new variable (scoped to the current function) called `test`, and assigns a value to that.

The values are identical in the two cases.